# Bcrypt - Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

Tags: python, unicode

The following code raises `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking`:

```
if request.form['username'] == admin[0][0]:
    if bcrypt.checkpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), admin[0][1]):
        print('checked')
```

But this section of the code returns `True` and therefore prints `checked`:

```
if request.form['username'] == username[0][0]:
    if bcrypt.checkpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), username[0][1]):
        print('checked')
```

`admin` & `username` are queries from an SQLite database, and they return a list with a tuple inside (i.e. `[('username')]`

The two snippets are nearly identical, and both are being encoded. So I am not sure why one works and the other does not.

Comment: Apparently, the hashed password for admin is coming back from the database as a Unicode string, but username's hashed password isn't.  I'm not sure why that would be the case, but applying ``.encode('utf-8')`` to the second parameter would likely fix this.

Comment: @jasonharper yes that fixed it! That is just so strange. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with encode to utf-8 for both the params, and use the hashpw with gensalt

where

user.password coming from SQLAlchemy db

form.password.data depicts password input in request

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(user.password.encode('utf-8'), 
                              bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data.encode('utf-8'),bcrypt.gensalt())):
```